# How to send MMS with MM4 using Java?

Tags: java, mms, mms-gateway

Please let me know, is there any way to send MMS messages using MM4 protocol in Java?

I found some sample projects sending SMS and MMS messages on Google and GitHub but they have used MM7 protocol to send messages. If there are some free APIs, please let me know about them too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MM4 interface is used for MMSC-to-MMSC connectivity. When you send an MMS to recipient outside your home mobile network message is sent from your MMSC over MM4 to recipients MMSC.

MM4 is based on SMTP with additional MMS specific headers. Operators don't use public internet for MM4, usually it will go through a VPN.

To send a message over MM4 you need to construct an email message in a correct format and send it to MMSC's SMTP port. There is a ton of examples all over the internet on how to send email with Java or any other language of your choice.

For specific MMS headers, ask operator for a sample message dump or check out MMS related specs from:

3GPP (http://www.3gpp.org/component/itpgooglesearch/search?q=MM4) (see 23.140)

OMA (http://technical.openmobilealliance.org/Technical/release_program/mms_v1_3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your information! It is really helpful. I continue to research about MM4 interface.

Comment: Really great info. It really helpful.